# Inline events not working (React+Express)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I understand there are similar questions out there and I have been through most of them.but I couldn't resolve my problem.

So I am trying out server side rendering with react and express and as the title suggests,I cant seem to get the event handlers working

After a couple of hours on google I reached a conclusion that I would need to render the application on the client side as well as the server side for the event handlers to work?how do i do that ?
I know how to serve just the React app with web dev server without using SSR
but how do I render the application on the client as well as the server??

I am new to react and express I am quite lost at this moment there were some tutorials suggesting that I try `hydrate()` on the client side but still nothing !
how do I enable event handlers while still achieving server side rendering??

**server file**

```html
import {TextBlock} from "../components/textblock/textblock"
    const path = require("path")
    var express = require("express")
    var React = require("react")
    const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');

    var app = express();


    app.get("*", (req, res) => {


        const markup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
            <TextBlock />
        )
        res.send(`<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>React and Webpack4</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <section id="index">${markup}</section>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index_bundle.js"></script></body>
    </html>
    `)
    })

    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log("server is listening");
    })
```

```
**Client**
```

```html
import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import {TextBlock} from "../components/textblock/textblock"


      ReactDOM.hydrate(<TextBlock/>,document.getElementById("index"));
```

```
**Webpack Config**
```

```html
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
    var path = require('path');

    const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    });

    const serverConfig = {
      entry: "./src/server/index.js",
      target: "node",
      output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, ""),
        filename: 'server.js'
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: "babel-loader"
            }
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'style-loader'
              },
              {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                  modules: true,
                  importLoaders: 1,
                  localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64]",
                  sourceMap: true,
                  minimize: true
                }
              }

            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }

    const browserConfig = {

      entry: "./src/browser",
      output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js'
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: "babel-loader"
            }
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'style-loader'
              },
              {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                  modules: true,
                  importLoaders: 1,
                  localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64]",
                  sourceMap: true,
                  minimize: true
                }
              }

            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      plugins: [htmlPlugin]
    }
    module.exports = [browserConfig, serverConfig]
```

```
React Component
```

```html
import React from 'react';
    import ReactDom from 'react-dom'


    export class TextBlock extends React.Component{
        constructor()
        {
            super()
            this.state=({count:1})
        }
        onComponentDidMount(){
            console.log("component loaded")
            
        }
       increment(){
            this.setstate({count:++this.state.count})
        }
        getState(){
            return this.state.count
        }
        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                <div onClick={(e)=>{this.increment()}} style={{border:"solid red 2px"}}>{this.getState()}</div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

It this how it supposed to be?? how does react take over if I am sending a rendered components through express?when does it take over?
Is there no way I could enable inline browser events?
while still achieving server side rendering?
Link to the Repo
https://github.com/xxxgrime/ssrerror

Comment: what do you mean by "event handlers" like ComponentDidMount and so on?

Comment: no I mean browser events like onclick,onmouseover,onfocus etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u have to enable disst folder for server.
as u can see in bunde javascript there is html not realy js
so in your index.js

```
app.use(express.static('./dist'));
```

and you have another problem there

```
increment(){
  this.setstate({count:++this.state.count})
}
```

this is function context. use arrow function or binde this to the function in constructor

```
increment = () => {
  this.setstate({count:++this.state.count})
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help i was missing this line =>  "app.use(express.static('./dist'))"

Comment: np, youcan check this as answered so i get some reputations :D

Comment: Already did that but my votes aren't recorded because my rep points <15 !!